# Meaning of 'amp' in an emotional-distress context

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does 'amp' mean in this phrase?

> I am glad they cannot read these signs so they won't get sad&amp

Comment: Although this question asks for what is tagged as "meaning-in-context," it breaks off before establishing the full context in which "sad&amp" occurs. To provide a better picture of what is going on, you should include more of the source quotation—specifically the rest of the sentence following "they cannot read these signs so they won't get sad&amp."

Answer (score 14):

It doesn't mean anything - it's a mistake.

In some pieces of computer software used to create web pages, to make an ampersand symbol **&**, you have to type **&amp;** instead.  The reason for that is well beyond the scope of this site, but a reference for form's sake is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

In this case, someone's tried to do that but got it wrong, ending up with the result you see.  It's not uncommon to see that happen, but it is just a mistake, and it doesn't have any meaning in the English language.

Comment: I find it a common programmer error in (content management) software, escaping(thats the term) the text by accident.

Answer (score 4):

&amp followed by a semicolon is an html code. You usually see that sequence in badly written web pages which is what appears have happened in your case.